# Access query only one column uses criteria

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2016

So, I want my query to do something like this. I would pull the data from a table but I want one column that pulls the data with a certain crtieria met. Here is what it would look like ideally:

[image]

I know I can't just change what is in the Criteria: field in Access because that will only limit everything that comes through the query, not just what is in the second Value column. So it must be an expression that I build for the Value, right? I'm just not sure what expression that would be.

I forgot to mention that I know how to do this using multiple queries, I would just like to be able to do it with only one query. When doing it with multiple queries I just find the Value associated with Group 2 for each type, then have that query result pulled as another column in the final query, with the value fields joined.

Comment: Don't understand what you are describing. That table is an example of raw data? ValueGroup2 field is a calculation? Exactly what is the criteria - what are the rules for filtering? You can nest query statements (subqueries).

Comment: The picture is what I want it to do. I just made that up in Excel. The Value Group 2 would be a calculation I think. So for example I want the calculated column to return the value of group 2 for each Type, just like the image shows.

Comment: You are correct when you say "I know how to do this using multiple queries".  It's ok to use multiple queries in SQL.  And sometimes it's the only way.  (Especially when you need data from other records in a group.)  Which is what you are doing here.  You need to group the "Types" and find the "Group" 2 "Value".  Then you can join that query to your overall query to grab your "Value (Group 2 for each Type)" field.  Other than that, in Access, the only way you'll get things in one pass is if you use vba and parse through a recordset.  But *that* is not the way to go.